# Does Princess Leia ever learn that Darth Vader is her father?

Tags: character, star-wars

As [asked on Quora](https://www.quora.com/Star-Wars-Movies-Does-Princess-Leia-ever-learn-that-Darth-Vader-is-her-father):

> Luke learns that he is Vader's son privately and finds out Leia is his sister in a separate revelation. Are these 2 points ever revealed to Leia, and what is her reaction to learning that the person who imprisoned her, tortured her, and destroyed her home planet is her father?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Yes, Luke tells her in *[The Return of the Jedi](http://www.blueharvest.net/scoops/rotj-script.shtml)*, on a footbridge in the Ewoks village.

First, he tell her that Vader is his father:

> LEIA
>   Luke, tell me. What's troubling you?
>
> LUKE
>   Vader is here...now, on this moon.
>
> LEIA (alarmed)
>   How do you know?
>
> LUKE
>   I felt his presence. He's come for me. He can
>   feel when I'm near. That's why I have to go.
>   (facing her) As long as I stay, I'm
>   endangering the group and our mission here.
>   (beat) I have to face him.
>
> Leia is distraught, confused.
>
> LEIA
>   Why?
>
> Luke moves close and his manner is gentle. And very calm.
>
> LUKE
>   He's my father.
>
> LEIA
>   Your father?

Immediately after, he tells her that she is his sister (and thus Vader's daughter).

> LUKE
>   There's more. It won't be easy for you to
>   hear it, but you must. If I don't make it
>   back, you're the only hope for the Alliance.
>
> Leia is very disturbed by this. She moves away, as if to deny it.
>
> LEIA
>   Luke, don't talk that way. You have a power
>   I--I don't understand and could never have.
>
> LUKE
>   You're wrong, Leia. You have that power too.
>   In time you'll learn to use it as I have. The
>   Force is strong in my family. My father has
>   it...I have it...and...my sister has it.
>
> Leia stares into his eyes. What she sees there frightens her. But
>   she doesn't draw away. She begins to understand.
>
> LUKE
>   Yes. It's you Leia.
>
> LEIA
>   I know. Somehow...I've always known.

Comment: There's also the scene with this dialog:
Han: "You love him?" Leia: "Of course" Han: "oh well then" Leia: "Oh no not in that way - he's my brother"

Comment: That scene comes right after the above dialog, just as Luke departs, Han shows up.